# Python; Application for Vehicle control using voice commands

Tags: python, pygame, speech-recognition

This is my code

```
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import QUIT

class CarControl:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 900))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.engine_running = False
        self.direction = (0, 0)  # Initially, the car is not moving
        self.speed = 5  # Initial speed

        self.car_image = pygame.image.load("car.png")
        self.car_rect = self.car_image.get_rect()
        self.car_rect.center = (200, 150)
        
        # Visual indicators for climate and multimedia control
        self.climate_indicator = False
        self.volume_level = 50  # Initial volume

        self.handle_command()

    # Rest of the methods remain unchanged

    def start_engine(self):
        if not self.engine_running:
            self.engine_running = True
            print("Engine has started.")

    def stop_engine(self):
        if self.engine_running:
            self.engine_running = False
            self.direction = (0, 0)  # Stop the car when the engine is off
            print("Engine has stopped.")

    def turn_left(self):
        if self.engine_running:
            self.direction = (-self.speed, 0)  # Set left movement
            print("Car is turning left.")
        else:
            print("Engine must be started to turn.")

    def turn_right(self):
        if self.engine_running:
            self.direction = (self.speed, 0)  # Set right movement
            print("Car is turning right.")
        else:
            print("Engine must be started to turn.")

    def go_forward(self):
        if self.engine_running:
            self.direction = (0, -self.speed)  # Set forward movement
            print("Car is moving forward.")
        else:
            print("Engine must be started to move forward.")

    def go_backward(self):
        if self.engine_running:
            self.direction = (0, self.speed)  # Set backward movement
            print("Car is moving backward.")
        else:
            print("Engine must be started to move backward.")

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
        print(f"Speed has been set to {speed}.")

    def draw_climate_indicator(self):
        # Draw visual indicator for climate control
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, (0, 255, 0) if self.climate_indicator else (255, 0, 0), (50, 50), 20)

    def draw_volume_indicator(self):
        # Draw visual indicator for volume
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(800, 50, 20, 100))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 0, 255), pygame.Rect(800, 150 - self.volume_level, 20, self.volume_level))

    def control_volume(self, direction):
        # Integrate logic for volume control here
        if direction == "increase":
            self.volume_level = min(self.volume_level + 10, 100)
            print("Volume has been increased.")
            # Add code to increase the sound system volume
        elif direction == "decrease":
            self.volume_level = max(self.volume_level - 10, 0)
            print("Volume has been decreased.")
            # Add code to decrease the sound system volume

    def control_climate(self, command):
        # Integrate logic for climate control here
        if "turn on climate" in command:
            self.climate_indicator = True
            print("Climate control has been turned on.")
            # Add code to turn on the climate control
        elif "turn off climate" in command:
            self.climate_indicator = False
            print("Climate control has been turned off.")

    def handle_command(self):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        running = True

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    running = False
                    
            if self.engine_running:
               self.direction = (0, -self.speed)
               self.car_rect.x += self.direction[0]
               self.car_rect.y += self.direction[1]

            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("Listening...")
                recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                audio = recognizer.listen(source)

            try:
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
                if "start" in text:
                    self.start_engine()
                elif "stop" in text:
                    self.stop_engine()
                elif "left" in text:
                    self.turn_left()
                elif "right" in text:
                    self.turn_right()
                elif "forward" in text:
                    self.go_forward()
                elif "backward" in text:
                    self.go_backward()
                elif "speed" in text:
                    words = text.split()
                    for word in words:
                        if word.isdigit():
                            self.set_speed(int(word))
                elif "increase volume" in text:
                    self.control_volume("increase")
                elif "decrease volume" in text:
                    self.control_volume("decrease")
                elif "turn on climate" in text or "turn off climate" in text:
                    self.control_climate(text)
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Unknown command")
            except sr.RequestError:
                print("Failed to recognize speech.")

            self.car_rect.move_ip(self.direction)
            self.car_rect.x += self.direction[0] * self.speed
            self.car_rect.y += self.direction[1] * self.speed

            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.screen.blit(self.car_image, self.car_rect)
            self.draw_climate_indicator()
            self.draw_volume_indicator()
            pygame.display.flip()
          
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    car_control = CarControl()
    car_control.handle_command()
```

I would like the car to move continuously when you give a vocal command but it only moves once per "voice command". I'm just starting to learn using voice commands andPygame (as you may see) so I'm thankful for any help.

I would like the car to move continuously when you give a vocal command but it only moves once per "voice command". I'm just starting to learn using voice commands andPygame (as you may see) so I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`recognizer.recognize_google` waits for new input. the function does not return until it has received and processed a new audio stream. So, you constantly pause the game loop and wait for a new input. For this reason, the car does not move continuously. I suggest to use `recognizer.listen_iter` which takes a callback function as input. The callback function will be called every time the recognizer receives a new data:

```py
def handle_audio(audio):
    try:
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')

        # do something
        # [...]

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Unknown command")
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Failed to recognize speech.")

# [...]

while running:
    # [...]

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.listen_iter(source, callback=handle_audio)
```